# Can Unity play a golem after playing Inspired Repair

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

Unity's card Inspired Repair's text says she can play a card. If inspired repair is played during her Play Phase, can she play a golem, which of course reads "cannot be played during the Play Phase."?

I would guess no, golems can't be played. But then I thought maybe golem's restriction means AS her Play Phase card. Perhaps the Play Phase ends as soon as the card is played, then it's between phases while the card effects play out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still her play phase so she can't play a mechanical golem no matter how many extra cards she is allowed to play.  During any other phase or other players turn she may play a mechanical golem if she gets to play a card.

Comment: This interpretation matches the way that the iPad works, so I believe it is correct.